# Forcing a WWAN connection on iPhone, even when Wi-Fi is available

Tags: iphone, networking, sockets

I need to make a network connection over WWAN (i.e. the mobile network) on an iPhone, even when the device is connected to a Wi-Fi network, however I can't find a way to do this.

I've tried going down to the socket level and iterating through the available interfaces, however when connected to Wi-Fi, the WWAN interface (pdp_ip0) disappears.

The solution needs to be App Store safe.

Comment: just wondering, why do you want to go to the WWAN?  In general Apple has an interest in limiting WWAN traffic, so I wouldn't be surprised if they don't provide a way to do this.

Comment: It's a non-negotiable operational requirement for the service the app needs to connect to.  The amount of data to be transferred is absolutely minimal - we're talking a few hundred bytes max.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is turning off the Wi-Fi connection.  Not sure if there's API for that or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324) code to determine if Wi-Fi is enabled, firing a `UIAlertView` to warn the users to quit the app, open the Settings app and switch off wireless manually. Not ideal, definitely.

Comment: Yes - I've been looking at the Reachability code. The problem is, requiring users to switch off Wi-Fi is the sort of thing that gets an app a flood of 1 star reviews in the App Store.

Comment: I hear you. Hope you find an answer -- I'm curious about this, myself.

Comment: I don't see how the Reachability code lets you determine whether Wi-Fi is enabled; only if you can reach a server with it.  But for geolocation, you only need to have it enabled, not actually use it for communication.  Is there a way to test the actual activation of Wi-Fi on the phone?

Answer (score 4):

Enumerate the network interfaces, you will see that when you're connected on both wifi and 3g, there are 2 with different local ip addresses. You might be able to use one vs the other by forcing a bind of your socket on the right interface before sending the data. The kernel which tries to find the best interface to route your packet should be happy with your choice.
Disclaimer: I have not tried this, this is just a suggestion.

Comment: I can confirm that this works fine when the cellular interface is up.  I am not sure about the case when the antennae is not already active.  I use the higher level http API to wake up the network before using my socket, and I can't control what interface that uses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to to do this. You need to tell the user to turn off the WiFi connection since "It's a non-negotiable operational requirement for the service the app needs to connect to."

In this scenario, the user is not likely to kill you with bad reviews if you are clear about why they have to disable WiFi.

-t